# Vue JS: Computed value vs. watcher

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have 3 Booleans at the start, and if one of these 3 values changes by the user (e.g. HTML checkboxes), I want to set `changed = true`.

```js
data()
  return {
    boolean1:false, //may initally be true/false
    boolean2:true,  //may initally be true/false
    boolean3:false, //may initally be true/false
    changed: false  //no changes to start with
  };
},
```

How do I track these 3 values properly in Vue? My impulse would be to use a watcher, but I now read several times that a computed property is the better choice for such tasks. Unfortunately, they didn't provide examples for such a simple tracking task, so how would a computed property look like? So far I have this:

```js
computed: {
  comp_settings_change: function(){
    // if booleans change, set to true, else stay at false.
    return true
  }
},
```

Comment: Your impulse is right, a watch is better because you only want to set a flag when an event fires

Comment: really depends on what you are trying to do, if you are just trying to detect if the booleans have changed from the initial state, then a computed would be simple, but you need to capture the initial state, that way if a boolean changes from false to true, then changed would be true, then if that boolean changes back to false, then changed would go back to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A watcher is more appropriate than a computed prop in this case because the flag only needs to be set *once*.

You could use [`vm.$watch()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) on the Booleans, which returns a function to stop watching after the initial change, allowing you to create a one-shot callback:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const unwatch = this.$watch(
      () => [this.boolean1, this.boolean2, this.boolean3],
      value => {
        unwatch()
        this.changed = true
      }
    )
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/one-shot-watcher-on-multiple-vue-props-dtyke?file=/src/components/CheckboxGroup.vue)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. So if I would wanted to watch the booleans constantly (not just set the flag once but on every change) I would use a computed value with this $watch function?

Comment: Come to think of it, a computed property with $watch() would probably just be a watcher :)

Comment: If you wanted to set the flag with every change to the Booleans, you could use the same solution but without `unwatch()`.